# question on multiline.pattern different examples

Tags: multiline, filebeat

new to filebeat and multiline.pattern configuration as a whole.

I was reading up on multiline.pattern examples and came across this
[multiline.pattern examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDzqJ.png).
where the example used was multiline.pattern: '^[[space]]'. But lets say if each line after the initial line beginning was a symbol like { or " instead of a whitespace, how do I put it?

multiline.pattern: '^{' or multiline.pattern: '^[[{]]' or something else entirely?

If I want to combine both options will it be multiline.pattern: '^{|^"' instead?

Sorry if it sounds like a dumb and simple question but I am not able to find any relevant/similar queries like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a usual regex pattern.

If you have set the:

```yaml
multiline.negate: false
multiline.match: after
```

It matches any line against the pattern and appends it to the previous line if match passes.

For your query that if the pattern start with `"` or `{` or `space`, the pattern would be:

```
^[[:space:]]|\{|[[:space:]]\"
```

You can refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html to get the more detailed examples.